# How to normalize test data in the same way as training data?

Tags: machine-learning, filtering, weka

I have used weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.Normalize in order to normalize my training data before building my model.

But now I face the question of normalizing the instances that I need to classify once the model is built.  weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.Normalize does not output parameters that I could use in order to normalize the attributes of my instance. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you intend to apply exactly the same normalization to training and test data. The way to do it is to make use of the *batch option*. You can find an explanation on how to do it in the command line at the [Batch Filtering page](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Batch+filtering).

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking.  Thanks a lot!